# Angular2, как вывести модальное окно?

Tags: angular4

Здравствуйте.
В Angular и JS в целом новичок.

Итак. есть Clarity UI.
Кнопка на стороннице по которой вызывается метод в компоненте этой страницы :

```
changeQty(restQty: number, uidItem: string)
  {    
    this.itemQtyUpdateService.updateItemQty(uidItem, restQty)
      .subscribe(
      (item: Item[]) => {
      this.item = item;
     //  тут  вызываем модальное окно
}
```

По завершении работы этого сервиса нужно открыть модульное окно с данными из объекта "item" этого метода.

В тщетных попытках была создана директива :

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core/';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core/';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appModal]'
})
export class ModalDirective implements OnInit { 

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.element);
    this.element.nativeElement.clrModalOpen = 'opened';
  }

  showModal() {
    this.element.nativeElement.clrModalOpen = 'true';
    console.log(this.element);
  }
}
```

В которой создан метод showModal() меняющий значения атрибута элемента "clrModalOpen" на как мне кажется активирующий окно.
Вот код модального окна из пакета Clarity ui:

```
<clr-modal appModal  [(clrModalOpen)]="opend" [clrModalClosable]="false">
  <h3 class="modal-title">No "x" in the top-right corner</h3>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p> Для </p>
    <p> По заказу </p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="opened = false">
      Я все правильно положил!
    </button>
  </div>
</clr-modal>
```

Код этот лежит в конце ХТМЛ страницы где его и надо вызвать.

---

Я исходил из следующей логики:
Создаю элемент в html коде -
Привязываю к нему директиву -
В директиве создаю методы меняющие его состояние-
вызываю методы директивы по необходимости из основного компонента.

что я делаю не так ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в компоненте добавте opened: boolean = false;

```
changeQty(restQty: number, uidItem: string)
 {    
  this.itemQtyUpdateService.updateItemQty(uidItem, restQty)
  .subscribe(
  (item: Item[]) => {
  this.item = item;
   this.opened = true;
}
```

Comment: все работает, спасибо!  промазал с комментарием

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот это:

```
opend =false;

showModal() {
    this.opend = true;
    console.log(this.element);
  }
```

Comment: Кажется на правильном пути:
теперь ошибка при сборке
[0m[1m[31mERROR in node_modules/@angular/animations/src/animation_builder.d.ts(9,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module './players/animation_player'.
[ERROR] [39m[22m[0m

Comment: все работает, спасибо !